# Symfony 5 - I can't login after logout on Heroku

Tags: symfony, authentication, heroku

When I login for the first time with the main login (login form), I have no problem with connecting.
Afterwards, if I logout, it seems I'm logout with no problem also.
But when I try to connect after the logout, I get an invalid credential message.

I don't have this problem in local.

I really don't see where the problem is coming from.

Here is my `security.yaml`

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    password_hashers:
        # Use native password hasher, which auto-selects and migrates the best
        # possible hashing algorithm (starting from Symfony 5.3 this is "bcrypt")
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            json_login:
                check_path: app_login_json
                username_path: email
                password_path: password

            provider: app_user_provider
            entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                invalidate_session: true
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                    google: "/login/check-google"
                    my_custom_provider: "/login/check-custom"
                    my_github: "/login/check-github"
                login_path: /login
                use_forward: false
                failure_path: /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Here my `LoginFormAuthenticator`

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck so I hope someone will see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I changed the template twig for the login with some of the elements I had in the Bootstrap theme I bought.
Thanks for those who read at least the question :)